# Display SharePoint App's Version Number

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app, app-part

I'm working on a SharePoint Hosted App that includes an App Part (or SharePoint Plugin, whatever they're calling it these days). Somewhere on the App Part, I thought it would be nice to display the current Version Number that I've defined in the App Manifest.

Is there any way to pass that version number into the Query String that's attached to my app web URL? Or perhaps a way via Javascript to obtain the same information?

Right now, I'm updating the value in both the App Manifest and in the HTML that defines my App's UI, just thought it would be nifty to only have one place to change.

Thanks in advance.